# Correct word/kanji for Precision

Tags: translation

im learning at the moment and stuck on if 精度 'Seido' is correct for 'precision' when describing a piece of measuring equipment as being precise or accurate? Would be very greatful if somebody could assist, confirm or correct me.

Comment: Related: [Science writing - exact, precise, or accurate](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69430/5010)

Comment: @naruto should this question be marked as duplicate or shall I update my answer with the details that you've included in yours?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Science writing - exact, precise, or accurate](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/69430/science-writing-exact-precise-or-accurate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Accuracy vs precision

Since your question is about the precision and/or accuracy of a piece of measuring equipment, I think it's especially important to mention that [accuracy and precision have distinct meanings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) in science, engineering, statistics, etc.

In short, the *accuracy* of a measurement indicates how close the measured value is to the true value, while the *precision* of a measurement talks about the uncertainty of your measurement. If you're asked to guess someone's height and also how confident you are of your answer, then *accuracy* refers to how close your guess is to their actual height, and *precision* refers to your confidence margin (within meters, centimeters, or feet or inches).

### To answer your question

So with the technical distinction in mind, the [Japanese version of the article above](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%A3%E7%A2%BA%E5%BA%A6%E3%81%A8%E7%B2%BE%E5%BA%A6) uses:

> Accuracy: 正確度{せいかくど}
>
> Precision: 精度{せいど}

For a lot of technical terms, including accuracy and precision, the 度{ど} at the end means *degree* or *magnitude*. Other examples are 温度{おんど} (temperature), 速度{そくど} (velocity) and 湿度{しつど} (humidity). For all of those words, you can use 〇度が高{たか}い and 〇度が低{ひく}い to mean *high value* and *low value* respectively.

Comment: Many thanks for your input. That's helped a great deal.